# JavaScript Interface Android WebView Call Java function From JS onclick

Tags: javascript, android-studio, webview, webview-android

Tengo todo este código pero no consigo que funcione JavaScript Interface para que con un boton html se ejecute una funcion en java que inicie una aplicacion con el método intent.

Estoy usando Webview chrome client, un archivo index.html ubicado en /main/assets que contiene los botones ,si alguien puede ayudarme, es urgente gracias.

```
// Enabling JS
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

// Java and Javascript interfacing
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptInterface(), "JsInterface");



// outside oncreate
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void FacebookIntentShare(Intent) {
        Facebook Intent
    }
}



<a href="#" onclick="FacebookIntentShare()">Iniciar Facebook</a>

  <button type="button" onclick="FacebookIntentShare();">Iniciar 
  Facebook</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function FacebookIntentShare(){
   //return value to Android 
   codigo que llame a una funcion de java...
la funcion de java debe lanzar un intent send to
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, deberías separar e indicar el código Java y el Javascript.

Comment: he seguido los pasos de tu respuesta pero el metodo public void FacebookIntentShare() no esta en uso y no funciona que hago? @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si defines de esta manera tu interfaz, esta se llamaría `"Android"`:

```
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface();
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "Android");
```

obviamente el método que deseas llamar debe estar declarado en la interfaz, importante declarar `@JavascriptInterface` :

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void FacebookIntentShare() {
     ...
     ...
    }

}
```

Por lo tanto cuando realices la llamada de los métodos dentro del código HTML debes especificar que es un método de la interfaz `"Android"`, por ejemplo:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Android.FacebookIntentShare()">Iniciar Facebook</a>
```

o simplemente:

```
   <a href="#" onclick="FacebookIntentShare()">Iniciar Facebook</a>
```

---

Ejemplo: **[Android Javascript Interface](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Javascriptinterface)**

Comment: he seguido los pasos de tu respuesta pero el metodo public void FacebookIntentShare() no esta en uso y no funciona que hago? @Jorgesys

Comment: FacebookIntentShare() debe estar declarada en el javascript del html, debes de cuidar que este método no tenga un error y que pueda ejecutarse. ¿Declaraste `@JavascriptInterface` ?

Comment: tengo esto pero no funciona dame mas detalles no ¿?      <script>FacebookIntentShare(){}</script>

Comment: debes definir la funcion: <script type="text/javascript">function FacebookIntentShare() { }</script> , pero además agrega lo que realizará el método. Si deseas puedes subir tu código en alguna parte y te ayudo.

Comment: public class JavaScriptInterface  extends MainActivity {
       public void FacebookIntentShare() {
        Toast.makeText(JavaScriptInterface.this, "MBS.corp", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           }

Comment: Todo esto lo tengo en mi MainActivity.this        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    
    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /** Show a toast from the web page */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void FacebookIntentShare() {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MBS.corp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

Comment: Todo esto es lo que tengo agregado pero no va
          <a href="#" onclick="Android.FacebookIntentShare()">Iniciar 
           Facebook</a>

            <script> function FacebookIntentShare()
            {Android.FacebookIntentShare}</script>

Comment: No entiendo porque -1 sin explicar, aún agregando un ejemplo funciona.

Comment: Me sale que el método no está en uso, no he compilado para saberlo pero tiene todo lo de tu ejemplo en un único Main Activity

Comment: Solucionado @JvascriptInterface sobre cada uno de los métodos es la solución.Pero alguien sabe porque al ejecutar un Toast me vuele a cargar la pagina html?  si la pagina es larga vuelve a la cabecera después de mostrar las alertas toast gracias.

Comment: si evitas el atributo href la pagina no recarga y si en el metodo ShouldOverrideurl juegas correctamente con los return true y false tampoco hace falta volver a llamar al metodo onload debido a que el error es sufragado...